# Get JSON data after it's stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

After getting JSON back from the ajax call, the data "response" is stored in the "theObj" variable; however, when I try to log "theObj" to the console, it results in multiple "[Object object]", even with JSON.stringify().

If I do a "theObj[0]" (response.results[0] works fine), I get "[", for the first character in "[Object object]".

Q: How can I store JSON in a variable and get the data back out afterward?

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

            for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
                //creating JSONenter[enter image description here][1]
                   theObj += response.results[i];
                    if (i == 18) {
                        //console.log(theObj.id)
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(theObj[0].id))
                     }
                 }
       }
```

Comment: try JSON.parse(theObj)

Comment: What is `theObj += response.results[i];` supposed to do? I'm unfamiliar with += on an object or array.

Comment: can you show us example value of 'response' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in the line

> `theObj += response.results[i];`

So try this instead

```
function (response) {
    var list = response.results;
    // if there is no reason for having 19, replace this with var end = list.length
    var end = Math.min(list.length, 19); 
    for(var index = 0; index < end; index++) {
        theObj.push(list[index]);
    }
    console.log(theObj);
}
```

We don't see the initialization of `theObj` variable

- If it is an array you should use the `push` function to add elements to it
- If it is a common object then use  `theObj[id] = list[index];`
- **DISCOURAGED** If it is a string then you should use  `theObj += JSON.stringify(response.results[i];) + ", ";`, then make sure that you add `}` or `]` at the end if it is an `object` or `array` respectively (and that it has also has `{` or `[` in the begining) and then use `JSON.parse(theObj)` to convert it back to an `object`

Please let me know which of the above are you using

Comment: I works! This makes so much sense. Also, I tried the discouraged method that you mentioned here prior to creating the post but forgot to add the brackets in, so that also failed.  Lastly, 19 is simply the number of columns I wanted to append to afterward.

Comment: @kennsorr then it's a good idea to use `Math.min(list.length, 19)` in case the list has less items

Comment: @kennsorr Also if you liked my answer you can upvote it as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

         $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
             console.log(val.id)
         });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to get the data as object and not a string.
For that you have to use `var object = JSON.parse(yourJSONString)`. This method returns an object based on your JSON string.

Example:

JSON result:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe"
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var john = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(john.name); //prints John Doe
```